# Verify the length of a Label after executing Javascript in UIWebView after auto-fill

Tags: javascript, ios, uiwebview

To make this clear I'm going to divide my question.

**Goal:**

After executing some Javascript check the a element on the page **ONCE**; but if it's incorrect I want to be able to recheck it on the press of a button.

**What I've tried:**

```
        -(IBAction)signin {

    [passwordTF resignFirstResponder];
    [usernameTF resignFirstResponder];

    //create js strings
    NSString *loadUsernameJS = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"var field = document.getElementById('login-form-username'); field.value='%@';", username];

    NSString *loadPasswordJS = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"var field = document.getElementById('login-form-password'); field.value='%@';", password];

    //autofill the form
    [mainWebView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:loadUsernameJS];
    [mainWebView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:loadPasswordJS];

    //auto login
    [mainWebView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@"document.getElementById('submit-login').click();"];


}

- (void)webViewDidFinishLoad:(UIWebView *)webView {

    NSLog(@"webViewDidiFinishLoad called");

    if (shouldVerify == YES) {

        NSLog(@"webViewDidiFinishLoad - shouldVerify YES");

        NSString *failedLogin = [mainWebView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString: @"document.getElementById('login-msg')"];

        if ([failedLogin isEqualToString:@"Failed login"]) {

            NSLog(@"webViewDidiFinishLoad - shouldVerify YES - failed");

            UIAlertView *WCE = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Wrong Credentials" message:@"The username or password you entered is incorrect please try again." delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"Ok" otherButtonTitles:nil, nil];
            [WCE show];

            [keychainItem resetKeychainItem];

            password = [keychainItem objectForKey:(__bridge id)(kSecValueData)];
            username = [keychainItem objectForKey:(__bridge id)(kSecAttrAccount)];

            [usernameTF setText:username];
            [passwordTF setText:password];


        } else {

            NSLog(@"webViewDidiFinishLoad - shouldVerify YES - success");

            ViewController *viewController = [[UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:nil] instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"ViewController"];

            UINavigationController *navBar=[[UINavigationController alloc]initWithRootViewController:viewController];

            navBar.navigationBarHidden = YES;

            [self presentViewController:navBar animated:YES completion:nil];
        }

        shouldVerify = NO;
    }
}

- (BOOL)webView:(UIWebView *)webView shouldStartLoadWithRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request navigationType:(UIWebViewNavigationType)navigationType {

    if (navigationType == UIWebViewNavigationTypeOther) {

        NSLog(@"shouldStartLoadWithRequest - shouldVerify YES");

        shouldVerify = YES;

    } else {

        NSLog(@"shouldStartLoadWithRequest - shouldVerify NO");

        shouldVerify = NO;

    }

    return YES;
}
```

**Problem:**

For some reason here:

```
if ([failedLogin isEqualToString:@"Failed login"]) {

            NSLog(@"webViewDidiFinishLoad - shouldVerify YES - failed");

            UIAlertView *WCE = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Wrong Credentials" message:@"The username or password you entered is incorrect please try again." delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"Ok" otherButtonTitles:nil, nil];
            [WCE show];


        } else {

            NSLog(@"webViewDidiFinishLoad - shouldVerify YES - success");

        }
```

The if statement always returns false and

```
  NSLog(@"webViewDidiFinishLoad - shouldVerify YES - success");
```

gets printed out when it shouldn't and failedLogin is equal to @"Failed Login". If I remove the else statement it always verifies the if statement as false login credentials when true, that's why I think I'm checking it before I should before it is processed.

**My guess:**

I'm running this if statement when the webView hasn't finished executing the javascript and/or reloading the webpage after button click.

**Resources:**

I don't know how this can help but the site I'm working with is: tapgram.com/login

The full current code is available here: http://pastebin.com/dnCn62FP
For full projet code please comment and I'll add the link.

Comment: What is the value of failedLogin?

Comment: Case for "Login" doesn't match. You are comparing "Failed login" with "Failed Login". You could use caseInsensitiveCompare: also.

Comment: it should be Failed login I mistyped it sorry.

Comment: If I remove the else statement it always verifies the if statement as false login credentials when true, that's why I think I'm checking it before I should before it is processed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error is in the JavaScript.

```
NSString *failedLogin = [mainWebView 
stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@"document.getElementById('login-msg')"];
```

returns the complete HTML string of the *login-msg* element.

So basically you are comparing `Failed login` with `<h4 id=​"login-msg" style=​"color:​red;​">​Failed login​</h4>`.

The JavaScript should look like this
`document.getElementById('login-msg').innerText` which will return **Failed login** in case the login really failed.

Comment: Can you do a NSLog of failedLogin?

Comment: it returns Failed login as I said. Is it easier if I check the URL of the page? (/login vs /loginfailed....(bucnh of characters)